# NodeList.item(0) returning null

Tags: javascript

I have a code snippet that is supposed to reveal rows of a list of scores, one by one, one second apart, but for some reason, it is throwing an error. Here is the code in question:

```
        const maxTeamsShown = 7;
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.score-row');
        console.log(rows);
        for (var i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            console.log(rows.item(i), typeof rows.item(i));
            setTimeout(() => {
                rows.item(i).classList.remove('invisible-div');
                if (i + maxTeamsShown < rows.length) {
                    rows.item(i + maxTeamsShown).classList.add('invisible-div');
                }
            }, 1000 * (rows.length - i));
        }
```

...and here are the console.logs that I get:

console.log(rows), when I'm testing, is just a single row:

```
NodeList [p.invisible-div.score-row]
0: p.invisible-div.score-row
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: NodeList
```

console.log(rows.item(i), typeof rows.item(i)):

```
<p class="invisible-div score-row">1. test - 36</p> 'object'
```

...so rows.item(0) exists.

However, within the setTimeout, rows.item(i) appears to be null, as the first line throws an error:

```
socketHost.js:258 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
at socketHost.js:258:18
```

So why does the object exist when I log it to the console, but suddenly, it is null when I need to modify its classList?

Comment: What happens if you comment out `rows.item(i).classList.remove('invisible-div');`? Also, where you say `invisible-div score-row`, do you mean to have a dot between them?

Comment: invisible-div score-row just means that both classes are applied to the <p> element. No dot needed.

The line you suggested commenting out is the whole point - I'm trying to remove the 'invisible-div' class so that the <p> is visible.

Comment: I have tried a workaround that didn't work, either - I tried giving each p.score-row an id of score-row-0, score-row-1, etc., and then referring to them with document.getElementById, but got the same error.

Comment: OK, so you're trying to remove a class from an item, but it ends up deleting the item itself? I'd still try commenting out the line I suggested just to confirm that's what's causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the `rows` variable, but with the iterator variable `i`. Within the timeout function, `i` has not the value you're expecting it to have. (Keep in mind the loop itself has actually long finished before the first timeout execution even occurs, so `i` ends up being `-1` for every call, which is not a valid index).

You need to pass the variable `i` to the timeout function like this:

```js
        const maxTeamsShown = 7;
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.score-row');
        console.log(rows);
        for (var i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            console.log(rows.item(i), typeof rows.item(i));
            setTimeout((i) => {
                rows.item(i).classList.remove('invisible-div');
                if (i + maxTeamsShown < rows.length) {
                    rows.item(i + maxTeamsShown).classList.add('invisible-div');
                }
            }, 1000 * (rows.length - i), i);
        }
```